# How to: Confluence overrides browser shortcuts (e.g. ⌘F)?

Tags: browser, shortcut, confluence

I just noticed that confluence opens its own search box, if you press ⌘F. How is this possible? I thought you can't override browser specific shortcuts like ⌘F? Does anyone know how they do this?
(Tested in Chrome.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only possible way to do that is by calling a :

```
event.preventDefault();
```